# What is this blue shadow called?

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

What is this blue shadow called which apears when the view is pulled after it ends? is there a listener triggered when this appears or goes?

[image]

I have implemented https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView and I want to load more items when this viewgroup is overscrolled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called as Overscroller.`Listview` has built-in support for overscrolling. Check out `setOverscrollMode` and related methods `setOverscrollHeader` and `setOverscrollFooter`. ListView makes use of the overscroll header/footer by overriding `AbsListView.onOverscrolled;` if you want different behavior, you can implement it by overriding it yourself.

Comment: I want it for viewgroup.. what to do?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html Also check this out http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Comment: For that check out the pull to refresh library!

Comment: it does not work....tried everything...even implemented an on scroll listener which fails in some cases.

Comment: your answer did not help but it gave me an idea on how to achieve my requirement.So accepting it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately there's no ready library or functionality to achieve that. But there're good open library that you can adapt.

My suggestion is to check `SwipeRefreshLayout`, it's on the Android support library.

This ViewGroup support a swipe from the top to give a callback, you probably can adapt it to implement a bottom swipe.

docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java

**edit:**
alternatively, to implement a `load more` function with scroll listener is relatively easy, it's just a simple `OnScrollListener` with the following code:

```
private long lastRequestTime = 0;
public void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
      if (((firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount) > totalItemCount - 4) &&
         (lastRequestTime + 1000 < System.currentTimeMillis())) {
         lastRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         // load more ...
      }
}
```

Comment: I achived it using goonerdroid's idea...thnx a lot for your help.I have this swipe refresh layout to refresh the view.